# Several inputs from a single input window

Tags: netlogo

Out of curiosity, I was trying to find a way to combine several inputs into a single input window (currently set to string) on the interface. In the current example, these inputs are the 4 parameters necessary for resize-world.
While my result works, I would be interested to hear if someone else knows a more elegant solution. I specifically dislike the use of `item` here.

Interface:

```
input-window 
[0 5 0 5]
```

Code:

```
to setup
  let worldsizes runresult input-window
  resize-world item 0 worldsizes item 1 worldsizes item 2 worldsizes item 3 worldsizes
end
```

Comment: relevant: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/pull/1139

Comment: That led me to this stackoverflow question which also seems quite relevant and interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541133/run-a-task-with-a-variable-number-of-arguments-in-netlogo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541133/run-a-task-with-a-variable-number-of-arguments-in-netlogo) as base, I created a procedure that allows a command, both anonymous and regular, to take a single list of arguments as input.

Interface:

```
input-window 
[0 5 0 5]
```

Code:

```
to test
  
  let worldsize run-result input-window ;creates a list
  
  apply-command "resize-world" worldsize
  
end



to apply-command [command inputlist]
  ; Takes two inputs
  ; 1: Anonymous command/string containing anonymous command/string containing regular command
  ; 2: A list of inputs, corresponding in length to the number of inputs the command takes
  ; Applies the command with the different items of the list as input
  ; Heavily inspired by stackoverflow-user Bryan head
  
  set command anonimify-command command length inputlist ; Using non-anonymous commands gave issues, hence they are anonimified
  (run listify-command command length inputlist inputlist)
  
end

to-report listify-command [ command num-args ]
  ; Takes an anonymous command and the length of a list as input
  ; Outputs an anonymous command that takes the different items of the list as inputs
  ; Heavily inspired by stackoverflow-user Bryan head
  
  if (not is-anonymous-command? command) [error "The first input for listify-command has to be an anonymous command"]
  
  let args (reduce word n-values num-args [ x -> (word " item " x " ?") ]) 
  ;show (word runresult (word "[ ? -> (run command " args ") ]"))
  report runresult (word "[ ? -> (run command " args ") ]")
  
end

to-report anonimify-command [ command number-of-inputs]
  ; Takes two inputs
  ; 1: Takes an anonymous command, a string containing an anonymous command or a string containing a regular command
  ; 2: Takes a number that corresponds to the number of inputs the anonimified command should take
  ; Returns anonymous commands unaltered
  ; Returns strings containing an anonymous command as an anonymous command
  ; Returns strings containing a regular command as an anonymous command
  
  if (is-anonymous-command? command) [ ; Anonymous commands get returned
    report command
  ] 
  
  if (is-string? command) [ ; Strings are processed
    carefully [ ; Using run-result on a string that does not contain an anonymous command causes an error, hence carefully
      if (is-anonymous-command? run-result command) [ 
        set command run-result command
      ]
    ]
    [
      let inputs n-values number-of-inputs [ i -> word " x" i]
      let inputs-as-string reduce word inputs
      let command-string (word "[ [" inputs-as-string " ] -> " command inputs-as-string" ]")
      set command run-result command-string
    ] 
    report command
  ]
  
  error "The inputted command must be either an anonymous command, a string containing an anonymous command or a string containing a command"
  ;If the input is neither anonymous command nor string, an error is displayed
  
end
```

Comment: Using this procedure with regular commands takes a factor 100 longer than with anonymous commands. I assume the problem is in the anonimify-command procedure

Comment: After another test, the problem seems to be the error suppressed by carefully. Removing carefully and the first command block of carefully, a regular command now gives very similar results to an anonymous command where the block is in place.